# ITextSharp PdfReader not reading new text in different PDFs

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have a windows services application that reads the text of PDFs using ITextSharp. I'm using a textbox to show the text of PDFs.
It works fine when it reads the first PDF, but when it reads the second PDF, the text does not change and the text is still of the first PDF. Here is my code :

```
dim vFileName as string
dim vFileEntries as string()
dim vPath as string = "C:\PDF"

if directory.exists(vPath) then
   vFileEntries = directory.getfiles(vPath)

  for each vFileName in vFileEntries
   dim PR as PdfReader = new PdfReader(vFileName)

    for CurrentPage as integer = 1 to PR.NumberOfPages
     RichTextBox1.text = ""
     dim ltestrategy as LocationTextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy
     dim currentext as string = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PR, CurrentPage,  ltestrategy)

     RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + currentext
     next
    PR.close()
  next vFileName
end if
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What happens if you remove `RichTextBox1.text = ""` (or at least move it outside the loop)?

Comment: i want to clear the text from the previous pdf, so, i can read the text of each PDFs

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking for.  What is the end result that you want in RichTextBox1 is the program runs, start to finish?  What is in the textbox after you run the code I posted?

Comment: i apologize for make you confused and my english is not good... but i want the end result is RichTextBox1 can show all text of all file PDFs. and what inside the textbox is just looping the text from first file PDF. acctually, i had a lot of PDF files that contain different text.

Comment: Have you tried logging the current text instead of showing it in some form element? That way you could try to determine whether it indeed is a question of iTextSharp behavior or of the behavior of your other components.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is set up now, it look like RichTextBox1.text will contain the text of the last page of the last pdf that got processed.  The following change will bring in the text from all pages of all pdfs processed from your folder.

To make this happen you will want to change the following:

```
for CurrentPage as integer = 1 to PR.NumberOfPages
     RichTextBox1.text = ""
     dim ltestrategy as LocationTextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy
     dim currentext as string = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PR, CurrentPage,  ltestrategy)

     RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + currentext
next
```

to:

```
for CurrentPage as integer = 1 to PR.NumberOfPages
     currenttext = ""
     dim ltestrategy as LocationTextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy
     dim currentext as string = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PR, CurrentPage,  ltestrategy)

     RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + currentext
next
```

where you are re-initializing `currentext` instead of `RichTextBox1.text`.  This will give you the text of all of the pdfs, with all of their pages, to the text box.

Comment: i 've tried the way you suggested and the text is still  not changed when read the next PDF... PdfReader is still reading the text from  the previous pdf.. i 've been using PdfReader.close() outside the loop to close file and read new file but it is not working..